# Rails Connection Pool Within Action Pack Request Cycle Same Connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Without manually calling checkout / checkin on the connection pool will a request cycle use a single connection for serial requests? For example, given the following snippet:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(...)
  @post = @user.posts.find(...)
  @blog = Blog.find(...)
  ...
end
```

Will each of the generated SQL calls (`SELECT * FROM users ...`, `SELECT * FROM posts ...` and `SELECT * FROM blogs ...`) be guaranteed to use the same connection in each case **or** will it potentially checkout / checkin a new / old connection between queries?

Furthermore - do long running transactions 'block' the connection pool (assuming this can only happen if a single connection isn't checkout on the start of a request and checkin at the end)?

```
User.transaction do
  @user.touch
  sleep 5
  @user.touch
end
```

**VS:**

```
@user.touch
sleep 5
@user.touch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation on ConnectionPool](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html) suggests that **there is only a single connection to the db used for each thread**.

Let me dive in the Rails 4.2 source code to support this claim:

- All finder methods (such as `Model.find(...)`) that are defined in the [`FinderMethods`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb) module eventually call some query method on the `connection` object.
- The `connection` (which can be also referenced as `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`) is [defined](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb#L83) in the `ConnectionHandling` module and it just calls the `ConnectionHandler` to [retrieve a connection](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L564).
- The `ConnectionHandler`, after finding the right database to get connection from (a rails project may use multiple databases), finally calls the **[`connection` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L254)**.

This method (as described in the [source code docs](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L254)) returns the connection **associated with the current thread**. Internally it uses a connections cache where the key is the `Thread.current.object_id`, i.e. a unique ID of the current thread.

So, based on this information, I think we can conclude that unless you worked with manually created threads in your code or unless you checked out the connection by yourself, **serial queries in a given model / controller should always be called on a single connection to the db**. And they should never checkout / checkin in between your queries as the thread is normally never switched during a single request.

On the other hand, all parts of code that use different threads to the request thread will use a different connection from the pool. Examples might be background jobs, manually created threads or different threads of the [Puma application server](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Puma-vs-Phusion-Passenger).

As of your second question about blocking - long-running queries will certainly block the current `connection` but the connection pool itself should still be perfectly available for other threads in the meantime (unless there are more threads than configured connections in the pool - the thread trying to retrieve the new connection would have to wait until some of the other threads finishes its work).